# Test Angular http service with Jasmine with phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I have been created 3 files to test a server RESTAPI with angular $http service with Jasmine.

When I load the SpecRunner.html with the CHROME browser then the test is running, and the http get request is sent to the server and the test validation is ok.

I download the phanton for win and write the following code in Phantom to load the index.html and run it, but the phantom load the SpecRunner.html and run the test but the http get request is not sent to the server.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), fs = require('fs'),

address = "file:///C://Users//bmp015//Desktop//jasmine-standalone//SpecRunner.html";
console.log('isFile? ' + fs.isFile(address));
console.log('isReadable? ' + fs.isReadable(address));

page.open(address, function(status){
    console.log('status? ' + status);
    console.log(page.content)

    var title = page.evaluate(function () {
        var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("jasmine-bar");
        return posts[0].innerHTML;
    });
    console.log("\n\n\n\n\n");
    console.log(title);
    phantom.exit();
    console.log("\n\n\n\n\n");
});
```

SpecRunner.html file load the angular files, jasmine standalone files and the test javascript files (files below).

SpecRunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.5.2</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.css">

  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <script src="code.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

code.js file - connect the server

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp.controller',[]).
  controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
  }])

/* Controller */
angular.module("MyApp", ['MyApp.controller']);

function logInSpecificIp(done)
{
   $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://10.100.102.102/web_project/index.php/v1/system/generalInfo'
}).error(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    expect(response).not.toBe(null);
    done();
}).success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    expect(response).not.toBe(null);
    expect(response).not.toBeUndefined();
    done();
});
};
```

test.js - Jamine test:

```
describe("Read general info", function () {

beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$http_, $injector) {
    $http = _$http_;
}));

it("run test 1=============================================", function (done) {
    logInSpecificIp(done);
});
});
```

Comment: Real requests shouldn't be sent in unit tests. And they cannot be sent when testing with ngMock. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: I didn't include the ngMock. Did I missed something? More than that from Chrome it working but not from phantomjs. Thanks

Comment: ngMock is included automatically when angular-mocks.js is loaded. The good question is why this works in Chrome, because it shouldn't. As I already said, no real requests should be performed in unit tests, and relying on them is wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to use the http angular service to send to server? Because if I remove the angula-mocks.js file, I got other errors in the jasmine. e.g. configure the jasmine ? Thanks   Regarding your comments about "no request should be performed in UT", we have already more than 1000 tests with this environment (run from chrome), but I would like to run it automatically from phantomjs.

Comment: There's no good way to do this, because not using real requests is the methodology behind unit testing. You test a service here, not a server. If you want to test how real app works, you can do this in e2e tests and Protractor.